# How to handle TIMESTAMP value that are out of allowed range in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, time, google-bigquery

I have a column where I'm trying to run the following calculation:

```
TIMESTAMP_DIFF((max(TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(safe_cast(ts as INT64)))), min(TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(safe_cast(ts as INT64))), SECOND) as session_length_in_seconds
```

when running my query I have the following error:

```
TIMESTAMP value is out of allowed range: from 0001-01-01 00:00:00.000000+00 to 9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999+00.
```

The `ts` column contains value in Unix time. It's a pretty big table and I suspect that only a few numbers of rows (less than 1%) are not correctly formatted.

How can I detect and filter out these malformed rows?

Comment: can you provide sample data for your problem

Comment: @nbk I can but this won't help to replicate the issue. the problem I have is that I get the errors but I don't know which rows are returning this error.

Comment: thats life we need these rows, to look for answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `SAFE.TIMESTAMP_MILLIS` instead of `TIMESTAMP_MILLIS`